# Update view in Fragment ViewPager from Activity crash

Tags: android

In my Activity have a ViewPager and a button update:

```js
public class Main7Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager vp;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
        vp = findViewById(R.id.vp);
        final AdapterEx adapterEx = new AdapterEx(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vp.setAdapter(adapterEx);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (vp.getCurrentItem() == 1 && adapterEx != null) {
                    AdapterEx fa = (AdapterEx) vp.getAdapter();
                    FragmentTow mstPeopleFragment = (FragmentTow) fa.getItem(vp.getCurrentItem());
                    mstPeopleFragment.update();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class AdapterEx extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public AdapterEx(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentOne();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentTow();
                default:
                    return new FragmentTow();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

In `FragmentTwo` I have two text: groups and teams, I want when page show `FragmentTwo` and click button update in activity, text `teams` will show and text `groups` will disable in `FragmentTwo`.
Here is code in `FragmentTwo`:

```js
public class FragmentTow extends Fragment {
    TextView textTeam;
    TextView textGroup;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        textTeam = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_team);
        textGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
    }
    public void  update(){
        textTeam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and here is xml in `FragmentTwo` `fragment_two.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_team"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="groups"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Teams"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

When click button update in Activity I will call `update()` function in `FragmentTwo` but it's crash with log: `Process: com.example.test2, PID: 32755
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test2.FragmentTow.update(FragmentTow.java:29)
        at com.example.test2.Main7Activity$1.onClick(Main7Activity.java:30)`
I try debug and see when I get fragment from activity it will return `FragmentTwo` in another local in stack so text in `FragmentTwo` will `NullPointerException` when call `update()`.
How I can update text in `FragmentTwo` when click button in Activity?

Comment: `ViewModel` and `LiveData` will save your life.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groups, container, false);
}
```

Is `R.layout.fragment_groups` the layout of your `FragmentTwo`? If not, `textTeam` and `textGroup` will be null

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    textTeam = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_team);
    textGroup = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
}
```

Comment: I pased xml of `FragmentTwo`. and fragment_groups is exactly content of `FragmentTwo`. sorry I will edit name

Comment: It return same result, App crash with NullPointerException textView

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to get the TextViews from the fragment in your Main7Activity using `mstPeopleFragment.getView()` like so:-

```
textTeam = mstPeopleFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_team);
textGroup = mstPeopleFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
```

then update them accordingly,so add this instead:-

```
//inside your btn listener in Main7Activity.java

FragmentTow mstPeopleFragment (FragmentTow)fa.getItem(vp.getCurrentItem());

textTeam = mstPeopleFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_team);
textGroup = mstPeopleFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_group); 

textTeam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
textGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But remember to keep them inside your button listener else it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. Update new `AdapterEx` with code:

```js
AdapterEx extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
   
    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
```

And when click update I call 
`FragmentTow fragmentTow = (FragmentTow) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
  fragmentTow.update();`
Thank every one for your time!
Thank you so much!